# How to print all submited value without getting overwrited everytime i click submit button (submit new value)

Tags: php, html

When I create a form and a submit button, I then print the input with `echo`, and it worked. The problem is every time I submit a new value, the printed old value is overwritten. How can I print both of them together, old and new? How do I print all the submitted values without getting overwritten every time I click the submit button?

An example:

[image]

If I input a new name (ex: `Garry`), it would delete `Johny` and write `Garry`. How can I print the name without getting overwritten?

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: If you want to store a value for later -  you need to preserve state - or rather save it somewhere.

Comment: Rather than posting the code in an image/screenshot, please copy paste the code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the names in an array in a session variable. For example:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['names'])) {
    $_SESSION['names'] = array(); // create empty array
}

$_SESSION['names'][] = $_POST['name']; // append item to array

?>
```

This should give you an idea.